# react useRef : current value is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a beginner's tutorial for the *useState* and *useRef* hooks, trying to implement a simple timer in react.

I'm using the `interval` variable to store the value from `setInterval()`

On click of start button, I am able to console.log the value of the interval correctly.
However on click of stop button, `interval.current` is console logged as `undefined`. The `stopTimer()` hence does not function as expected.

Why does interval.current print undefined when it is clearly set in startTimer (and logged there)? What am I missing here?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const pad = (time) => {
  return time.toString().padStart(2, "0");
};


function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("Pomodoro!");
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(5);
  const interval = useRef(null);

  const startTimer = () => {
    interval.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((timeLeft) => {
        if (timeLeft >= 1) {
          return timeLeft - 1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }, 1000);
    console.log(interval.current, " :in start");
  }

  const stopTimer = (interval) => {
    console.log("in stop: ", interval.current);
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }

  const resetTimer = () => { }

  const minutes = pad(Math.floor(timeLeft / 60));
  const seconds = pad((timeLeft - minutes * 60));


  return (

    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>
        <span>{minutes}</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>{seconds}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={stopTimer}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={resetTimer}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

output in console

> 6 " :in start"
> in stop:  undefined

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because you pass a lower scope variable called `interval` to `stopTimer`, but when you call `stopTimer` you do not pass the argument, so it is undefined when you're accessing it.

You probably referring to `interval` you've defined as `ref` so you need to just access it without passing `interval` to `stopTimer`, try this:

```
  const stopTimer = () => {
    console.log("in stop: ", interval.current);
    clearInterval(interval.current);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering what your code is doing, I believe `interval` should be a state variable and not a ref. That is to say, you should use

```js
const [interval, setInterval] = useState(null);
```

instead of `const interval = useRef(null);`

Refs are used to be linked to DOM elements (for instance a form element you wish to refer to when a button is clicked). It's only when a ref variable is correctly referencing a DOM element that their `current` attribute is defined.

Comment: Though ref is often used to anchor DOM elements, it's not restricted to that.